# Stopping a checkbox control from being positioned in the front

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to position my check box control behind an image i have created on my form. When writing the routine on the on-click command all is fine. Unfortunately, for some strange reason, upon loading the form, the same code does not work.I have set the postion to "send to back" but with no success..  Here is my code (if it helps)..   'LackOfFocus1' is the checkbox controlwhich I have set to 'send to back' while 'X1' is an image which i would like to see, superimposed OVER 'LackOfFocus1'..  Unfortunately, on the on load event, it does the opposite of what I would like to do.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If LackOfFocus1 = -1 Then

        Me.x1.Visible = True

Else

    Me.x1.Visible = False

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and logical solution found.  The issue was caused the fact that the form in question is a subform and therefore the event should not be ON LOAD but ON CURRENT:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
 If LackOfFocus1 = -1 Then
    Me.x1.Visible = True
Else
    Me.x1.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```